# Travis CI Android build keep failing with gradlew no such file

Tags: java, android, travis-ci

my travis ci build keeps failing with,

$ chmod +x /.gradlew
chmod: cannot access ‘/.gradlew’: No such file or directory
The command "chmod +x /.gradlew" failed and exited with 1 during .

I tried all the suggestions, different yml files but cant get rid of this error.

My travis yml is on root directory, the here is my folder structure

root: /src .gitignore .travis.yml

src: /client /server

client: /app /gradle/wrapper build.gradle gradle.properties gradlew gradlew.bat settings.gradle

Here is my travis.yml

```html
sudo: false
language: android
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-25.0.3

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-25
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-19

before_install:
  - chmod +x /.gradlew
script:
- "/.gradlew clean build"
notifications:
  email: false
```

and here is my build.gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3.3'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug this you could change the `before_install` section to print current directory and list its contents.

```html
before_install:
  - pwd
  - ls -la
  - chmod +x /.gradlew
```

Comment: This actually helped i found that it wasn't in the right directory, now i did before_install:
  - cd src/client
  - pwd
  - ls -la
  - chmod +x /.gradlew

it lists everything correctly in the correct directory but still says gradlew not found eventhough there is the gradlew file there

Comment: I got it to work with adding cd src/client under before_script not before install! thank you for your help

Comment: @JohnFraks, would mind sharing your .travis.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Add this .yml file

```
- name: Check Directory
  run: - pwd
       - ls -la
       - cd android && chmod +x ./gradlew
- name: Build Command
        run: cd android && chmod +x ./gradlew
```